# Type.GetType("Namespace.Classname, Assemblyname") returns null

Tags: c#

Here is my code

```
public static string dalProvidor = "SimpleInjector.EFDataProvider.EFDataProvider";
string dalrep = dalProvidor + ", SimpleInjector.EFDataProvider";
string d = typeof(SimpleInjector.EFDataProvider.EFDataProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName;
Type dalRepository = Type.GetType(dalrep);
```

I am reading the AssemblyQualifiedName into a variable **d** but i am not using it anywhere in the code. I am storing the "Namespace.Classname, Assemblyname" in a string variable **dalrep**. I am passing the **dalrep** to Type.GetType.

I observed two results :

> 1. If i comment the below line, Type.GetType returns me null for **dalrep**

`string d = typeof(SimpleInjector.EFDataProvider.EFDataProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName;`

> 2. If i uncomment the above line, Type.GetType returns me the correct type for **dalrep**

I do not know why it is returning me two different results for the same code, depending on the below line even though i am not using **d** anywhere

`string d = typeof(SimpleInjector.EFDataProvider.EFDataProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName;`

My requirement is, I need to store "Namespace.Classname, Assemblyname"  in database and read the "Namespace.Classname, Assemblyname" from database and pass it to type.gettype.

Can someone please help me out on this?

**Update**
The code works as expected now. I dont know what happened, it just works fine now. I did not make any change. The below line is commented

```
string d = typeof(SimpleInjector.EFDataProvider.EFDataProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

and Type.Gettype does not return me null. Weird. same code did not work yesterday and it worked today

**Update**
Again the GetType is returning me null. I dont know whats happening. Same piece of code worked ten min back and again it stopped working.

Comment: If the line is commented, do you still have `SimpleInjector.EFDataProvider.dll` inside the bin/Debug folder?

Comment: Try calling `Assembly.Load` before `GetType`, does it work then?

Comment: The dll must exist in the same directory as your entry point assembly to be able to be loaded in this way

Comment: Yes the dll is always present in the bin/debug folder of the entry point assembly. I tried assembly.load and it works perfectly well.. For assembly.load i need to pass the absolute path which is a hardcoded value and will change on deployment on different servers and hence not feasible. I need to fetch the "Namespace.Classname, Assemblyname" from database and pass it to gettype

Comment: If i pass it as a string to GetType it returns me null, as i described in my query

Comment: I am sorry.. dll is not present in bin/debug folder of entry point assembly.. I  have balUnittest assembly which is the entry point assembly. balunittest calls another assembly named InstanceManager, inside this assembly i have the dlls..